# show that $a^2+b^2+c^2+2abc+3\ge (1+a)(1+b)(1+c)$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, pigeonhole-principle, substitution, uvw

> let $a,b,c>0$. Show that
>   $$a^2+b^2+c^2+2abc+3\ge (1+a)(1+b)(1+c)$$

By the
$$(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)=1+a+b+c+ab+bc+ac+abc$$
it is suffient to show 
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+abc+2\ge a+b+c+ab+bc+ac$$
How?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+2+abc\geq a+b+c+ab+ac+bc$$ or $f(v^2)\geq0$, where
$$f(v^2)=9u^2-6v^2+w^3+2-3u-3v^2.$$

But $f$ is a linear function,

which says that it's enough to prove our inequality foe an extremal value of $v^2$,

which happens for equality case of two variables.

Since our inequality is symmetric, we can assume $b=c$ and it's enough to prove that
$$a^2+(b^2-2b-1)a+b^2-2b+2\geq0,$$
for which it's enough to prove that
$$(b^2-2b-1)^2-4(b^2-2b+2)\leq0$$
for $b^2-2b-1\leq0$ or
$$(b-1)^2(b^2-2b-7)\leq0,$$
which is obvious.

Done!

Another way.

Since $$\prod_{cyc}((a-1)(b-1))=\prod_{cyc}(a-1)^2\geq0,$$
we can assume that $$(a-1)(b-1)\geq0$$ or
$$c(a-1)(b-1)\geq0$$ or
$$abc\geq ac+bc-c.$$

Thus, it remains to prove that
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+2+ac+bc-c\geq ab+ac+bc+a+b+c$$ or
$$a^2+b^2+1-ab-a-b+(c-1)^2\geq0$$ or
$$\frac{1}{2}((a-b)^2+(a-1)^2+(b-1)^2)+(c-1)^2\geq0.$$
Done again!

Comment: have you other  simple methods to prove it?

Comment: @communnites I added something. See now please.

Answer (score 1):

$$a,b,c \ge 0$$

$$a^2+b^2+c^2+2abc+3\ge (1+a)(1+b)(1+c) \Leftrightarrow $$

$$\Leftrightarrow (a-1)^2+(b-1)^2+(c-1)^2\ge (1-a)(1-b)(1-c)$$

Which is obviously.

Comment: What is the rest? Why it's true?