# if $a,b,c$ are positive prove that $a^2+b^2+c^2+2abc+3\ge (1+a)(1+b)(1+c)$

Tags: inequality

> if $a,b,c$ are positive prove that $$a^2+b^2+c^2+2abc+3\ge (1+a)(1+b)(1+c)$$

I have tried to use the  p-q-r method.

let $p=a+b+c,q=ab+bc+ca,r=abc$

we have to prove $$p^2-3q+r+2-p\ge 0$$

as $p^2\ge 3q$ we have to prove $$r+2-p\ge 0$$.
but i don't think this is true. Also i know the following inequalities but i can't figure out how to use them.

- $pq\ge 9r$
- $2p^3+9r\ge 7pq$
- $q^3\ge 27r^2$ etc. etc.

Please note that i am looking for a solution **only using pqr**.I would be grateful if anyone can explain their logic behind the proof as it is the first time i am using 'pqr' method.

Comment: The first $pqr$ statement ($p^2-3q+r+2-p\ge 0$) is true where equality holds for $p=q=r=1$. The second statement is not necessarily true, as it should be $p^2 ≥ 2q$.

Comment: Isn't [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358305/show-that-a2b2c22abc3-ge-1a1b1c) by Michael Rozenberg what you want?

Comment: The inequality $r+2-p\ge0$ need not hold: $r$ can be made as small as you like by letting $c$ be close to $0$, while at the same time $p$ can be made as large as you like by letting $a$ and $b$ be large.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, of course. The topic starter looks for explanation, how $uvw$ or $pqr$ method works, which we can not see in the linked topic.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Is your answer to the linked question not by $uvw$? The first part is almost identical to your new answer...

Comment: @Arnaud D  See please better my post here. The "first identical part" it's first four lines in my post. It's less than 10% of my post.

Comment: Just post your answer in the duplicate target, @MichaelRozenberg, we want to group all the answers in one post.

Comment: @Arctic Char It would be very bad because they are different questions. See please better a question here. I think we need to wait before, what Albus Dumbledore will say.

Comment: The question is a duplicate.  Posting a new answer to the older question would be appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality $r+2-p \geqslant 0$ does not true, example $a = 2, b = 1, c = \frac 12.$

We need to prove
$$p^2-p-3q+r+2 \geqslant 0,$$
equivalent to
$$(p^2+2r+1-4q)+(p^2-2p-2q+3) \geqslant 0.$$
Because
$$p^2-2p-2q+3 = (a-1)^2+(b-1)^2+(c-1)^2 \geqslant 0.$$
It's remain to prove that
$$p^2+2r+1 \geqslant 4q.$$
Using the AM-GM inequality, we have
$$2r+1 \geqslant 3\sqrt[3]{r^2} \geqslant \frac{9r}{p}.$$
Therefore, we will show that
$$p^2+ \frac{9r}{p}\geqslant 4q.$$
Which is Schur inequality.

**Note.** See [here](https://nguyenhuyenag.files.wordpress.com/2020/07/darij-grinberg.pdf) (page 4, Vietnamese).

Comment: In my opinion, you used AM-GM and Schur and not a $uvw$ or $pqr$ method.

Answer (score -1):

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+abc+2\geq a+b+c+ab+ac+bc$$ or $f(v^2)\geq0,$ where
$$f(v^2)=9u^2-6v^2+w^3+2-(3u+3v^2)=9u^2-9v^2+w^3+2-3u.$$
But $f$ decreases, which says that it's enough to prove our inequality for a maximal value of $v^2$.

Now, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are roots of the equation $$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=0$$ or
$$x^3-3ux^2+3v^2x-w^3=0$$ or
$$-x^3+3ux^2+w^3=3v^2x.$$
Now, let $u$ and $w^3$ are constants and $v^2$ is changed. In this situation $a$, $b$ and $c$ are changed.

Since the last equation has three roots $a$, $b$ and $c$, we see that a graph of $g(x)=-x^3+3ux^2+w^3$ and the line $y=3v^2x$ have three common points and $v^2$ gets a maximal value for equality case of two numbers between $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Actually, if $a\leq b\leq c$ we can see that it happens for $b=c$.

Indeed, easy to draw a graph of $g$: $(0,w^3)$ it's a minimum point of $g$, $x_{max}=2u$ and the line $y=3v^2x$ goes across the origin.

If $v^2$ increases, so the line $y=3v^2x$ is  rotated and we can see, that $v^2$ may be maximal, if we want that our equation would have three positive roots, when $b=c$.

Id est, it's enough to prove our inequality for equality case of two variables.

Since our inequality is symmetric, it's enough to assume $b=c$ and we obtain a quadratic inequality of $a$ and the rest is smooth, which you can see here: [show that $a^2+b^2+c^2+2abc+3\ge (1+a)(1+b)(1+c)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358305/)

Comment: I think there was a bit of confusion(my fault) actually i was looking for the answer given by nguyen_ag,that is what i meant.But your answer is very helful as i did't know how the uvw worked ,so please don't delete it.Thank you!